# Preserving div parent height alongside child div content horizontal centering

Tags: css, html, centering

So I have been searching around trying to figure out how to make a parent div's height equal to that of its largest child, while making the children all the same maimum height and enforcing a horizontal vertical center on all the children, which may contain images. In short, the result of using a table with two columns and one row, with align and valign set to center.

For the following html,

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="col1">
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the css for making all children the same (maximum) height, such that the centering of the contents of each column is possible while expanding the parent to encompass and not hide its child data is...?

Initially I tried to use [this](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks), but it did not correctly expand each column to the maximum height, and thus preventing the desired vertical centering of the contents of each child.

Some also suggested using the `overflow: overlay;` or `overflow:auto;` css property, but this produced scroll bars everywhere.

Any help would be great... Tables are looking really good right now...

Comment: May you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: @Ali made one for us :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `display:inline-block;` ?

```
.col1,.col2
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:200px;
    border-style:solid;
}
.inner
{
    border-style:solid;
    text-align:center;
}
.col1
{
    height:300px;

}
.col2
{
    height:200px;
}
```

The two columns will be beside each other, and the height of `.inner` will be decided by the tallest column, in this situation, `.col1`. Check it out : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/68Lrb/)**

Comment: If I could reach over and shake your hand, I would do so! `display:inline-block;` is much easier than floating left and right and allows the expansion of the parent while maintaining the ability to center vertically! Thanks man, this is brilliant!